# Restrict register path in FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, post, fosuserbundle

I am using login and register on the same page with fosuserBundle in my Symfony application (I have the same structure that [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311189/login-and-register-in-same-page-with-fosuserbundle). All works perfectly without any problem. But now if I go to the /register url, I am getting register form rendered. If it is possible I want that the user has just access to register form in login template.

I thought about don't allow get requests to register path, but I am not sure if it is the correct way or there is another better way to achieve it

I'd be grateful if someone can help me with my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acces /register because you imported all FOSUserBundle routes like this

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

or like this

```
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

the registration.xml routing file is necessary because it has routes that will save your user in the database after registration so you can't really delete its importation

you can work around it by defining a route with path /register before importing the FOSUserBundle routes and have redirect to to your (login and registration) page, when the user goes to **/register** url Symfony will start looking for a match in the **app/config/routing.yml* file and will return the first match it finds which will be your newly defined route and not the register route from FOSUserBundle

It's not really a solution it's more like a hack, i had the same problem in one of my projects and it worked just fine

I hope this helps

Comment: Perfect! I will use this hack, thanks for your help!!